# Find the employee names who have been hired in the month of February from the following table

Tags: mysql, database

```
select empname, hiredate from employees 
inner join Dept on employees.deptid=Dept.deptid;

empname hiredate
SMITH   1980-12-17
ALLEN   1981-02-20
WARD    1981-02-22
JONES   1981-04-02
MARTIN  1981-09-28
BLAKE   1981-05-01
CLARK   1981-06-09
SCOTT   1982-12-09
```

I am getting this result after firing the above inner join query; I want to add in this query to find the employee names whose hiring month is February. how can I do it?

Comment: Read about the where clause and see how can you apply it to the results of the query. In case of data from multiple tables, you need to use table aliases and then you can apply where clause on any of returned attributes from any table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `WHERE` clause which checks for February:

```
SELECT empname, hiredate
FROM employees e 
INNER JOIN Dept d
    ON e.deptid = d.deptid
WHERE MONTH(hiredate) = 2;
```